# Unable to allocate memory for an array

Tags: pandas, csv, memory, jupyter-notebook

I have a system with 8GB RAM, 0.5  TB HD on which I'm trying to load a CSV file of 1.2 GB using Jupyter Notebook. I am getting the following error:
Unable to allocate 64.0 KiB for an array with shape (8192,) and data type int64

Is there any way as to how can I load my file without the notebook crashing down?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the array?

Comment: I am not loading an array, but importing a csv file with around 100 columns

Comment: Ok. Then, share a sample of the csv (as text) and the code you use to import (e.g., ```df = pd.read_csv("files.csv", sep=";")```).

Comment: Any csv with columns 1-100 can be a sample in this case...as the issue is it doesn't load the csv of size 1.2 GB

Answer (score 0):

This means your RAM is filled and your Memory does not have space to allocate for new variables anymore. The obvious answer would be to look into other Jupyter notebooks which has big dataframes loaded as variables and just shut down those kernels which you do not need anymore. A more throught investigation woul be to look into Activity monitor or Task manager and see which program takes a lot of RAM and deal with that program.